# Scripts disabled redirecting

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

I have an index page that detects if users have JavaScript and cookies enabled before going to the Login page.  The login page will only show the login form if both are enabled.

I first set a cookie on the index page.  If the cookie is read on the Login page, then cookies are enabled.  If JavaScript is disabled, it redirects to the login page with a querystring letting me know it failed.

My problem now is that the redirect in the  keeps firing even when scripts are enabled.  What do I need to change here?

```
<html>
<head>

<%
    response.cookies("enabled")="1" 
%>

<noscript>
    <%response.redirect("http://www.test.com/test/login.asp?noscript=true&settingsCheck=1")%>
</noscript>
<%
    response.redirect("http://www.test.com/test/login.asp?&settingsCheck=1")
%>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOSCRIPT` is a client tag. `<% ... %>` executes server-side. Thus, the code inside the `NOSCRIPT` tag is still evaluated on the server regardless of the surrounding markup.

You could use a `META` refresh tag to accomplish the redirect on the client. This does not require script, so it could be placed within the `NOSCRIPT` tag. This is [valid HTML 5 markup](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/meta.http-equiv.refresh.html).

```
<noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.foo.com?script=false">
</noscript>
<script>
    window.location.href = "http://www.foo.com?script=true";
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! That makes sense.  I put it in and the issue I'm having now is that the meta tag redirect isn't happening even when scripts aren't enabled.  The second asp redirect is still the one that's sent. I'm not sure what else I need to change.

Comment: @Cineno28 - I updated my example. You can use a client-side redirect; that way, if script is not enabled, the meta tag will redirect, but if it **is** enabled, the script will handle the redirect.

Comment: Thanks it's working now.  I really appreciate the edit too.  Thank for the help!